# How to implement always expand first 2 nodes in treeview when start or after filter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have a sample project with mvvm and collection to construct the tree view.

I would like to know how to implement always expand first 2 nodes when start or after filter the tree view.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTVHierarchicalDataTemplateFilter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:loc ="clr-namespace:WpfTVHierarchicalDataTemplateFilter"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <CheckBox Content="Green" Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDisplayGreen, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <CheckBox Content="Yellow" Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDisplayYellow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <CheckBox Content="Red" Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDisplayRed, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="False" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ClassList}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Class}" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Margin="2" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Student}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Margin="2" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

View Model

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private bool _isDisplayGreen = true;
    private bool _isDisplayRed = true;
    private bool _isDisplayYellow = true;

    public bool IsDisplayGreen
    {
        get { return _isDisplayGreen; }
        set
        {
            _isDisplayGreen = value;
            FilterFunction();
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayRed");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayGreen");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayYellow");
        }
    }

    public bool IsDisplayRed
    {
        get { return _isDisplayRed; }
        set
        {
            _isDisplayRed = value;
            FilterFunction();
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayRed");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayGreen");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayYellow");
        }
    }

    public bool IsDisplayYellow
    {
        get { return _isDisplayYellow; }
        set
        {
            if (value == false)
            {
                _isDisplayGreen = value;
            }

            _isDisplayYellow = value;
            FilterFunction();
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayRed");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayGreen");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDisplayYellow");
        }
    }

    private void FilterFunction()
    {
        ICollectionView classesDataSourceView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ClassList);

        classesDataSourceView.Filter = (classModel =>
        {
            ICollectionView studentsDataSourceView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((Class)classModel).Students);

            if (_isDisplayGreen == false && _isDisplayYellow == false && _isDisplayRed == false)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => false);
            }

            if (_isDisplayGreen == true && _isDisplayYellow == true && _isDisplayRed == true)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => true);
            }

            if (_isDisplayGreen == false && _isDisplayYellow == true && _isDisplayRed == false)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Yellow-icon.png"));
            }

            if (_isDisplayGreen == true && _isDisplayYellow == false && _isDisplayRed == false)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Green-icon.png"));
            }

            if (_isDisplayGreen == false && _isDisplayYellow == false && _isDisplayRed == true)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Red-icon.png"));
            }

            if (_isDisplayGreen == true && _isDisplayYellow == false && _isDisplayRed == true)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Red-icon.png") || ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Green-icon.png"));
            }

            if (_isDisplayGreen == false && _isDisplayYellow == true && _isDisplayRed == true)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Red-icon.png") || ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Yellow-icon.png"));
            }

            if (_isDisplayGreen == true && _isDisplayYellow == true && _isDisplayRed == false)
            {
                studentsDataSourceView.Filter = (studentModel => ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Yellow-icon.png") || ((Student)studentModel).ImagePath.Equals("../Images/Green-icon.png"));
            }

            return !studentsDataSourceView.IsEmpty;
        });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Class> classList;

    public ObservableCollection<Class> ClassList
    {
        get { return classList; }
        set { classList = value; }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        classList = GetAll();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Class> GetAll()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Class> classList = new ObservableCollection<Class>();
        Class treeItem = null;
        string greenIconPath = "../Images/Green-icon.png";
        string redIconPath = "../Images/Red-icon.png";
        string yellowIconPath = "../Images/Yellow-icon.png";

        treeItem = new Class("Class A", redIconPath);
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 1", greenIconPath));
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 2", greenIconPath));
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 3", redIconPath));
        classList.Add(treeItem);

        treeItem = new Class("Class B", yellowIconPath);
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 1", yellowIconPath));
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 2", greenIconPath));
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 3", greenIconPath));
        classList.Add(treeItem);

        treeItem = new Class("Class C", greenIconPath);
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 1", greenIconPath));
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 2", greenIconPath));
        treeItem.Students.Add(new Student("Student 3", greenIconPath));
        classList.Add(treeItem);

        return classList;
    }
}
```

[Sample project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=233E2A690341BB1D!484&authkey=!AFN8y4CKh1uPjyI&ithint=file%2Crar)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by binding. Use the TreeView.ItemContainerStyle property:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ClassList}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Class}" ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Margin="2" Source="{Binding ImagePath}">
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:Student}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Margin="2" Source="{Binding ImagePath}">
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You will then have to put an IsExpanded property on your Class and Student ViewModels. These should notify a property changed event when changing, so they need to extend INotifyPropertyChanged e.g.

```
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get
    {
        return m_IsExpanded;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(m_IsExpanded, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        m_IsExpanded = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
    }
}
```

You can then set Class.IsExpanded = true on the object you want to expand when applying the filter (or whenever you want to from the ViewModel).

Comment: Hi Histonivich,

Thanks for your reply, may I ask why you write this section of code?

if (Equals(m_IsExpanded, value))
        {
            return;
        }

Comment: This is just best practice from my experience.

Generally you don't want to be updating the UI with a property change event if it is not needed. Likewise, if the UI updates the property, it is possible it might try and do this many times depending on the setup of the View (such as UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged being set on a binding etc.)

In your problem case, you can omit it if you don't need it.